# Change text on div, if change value of input JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my code:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100000,
      step: 5000,
      value: 5000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Стоимость:</label>
  <input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" size="4">Р
</p>
```

This is trackbar. I want to change text on div, when change value of input. Pls, help with js code.

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: I don't understand, which div?

Answer (score 1):

Give the div an ID, say, "result",

Then in under $("#amount").val(ui.value);, add:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=ui.value;
```

(Edited)

Comment: Any reason why the down vote? Help me improve my answer next time. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then use document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=ui.value. Why do people stick to jQuery syntax for even the most trivial tasks? And thank you BlackSheep for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

In your example I do not see a `<div id="slider-vertical"></div>` for the vertical slider in your HTML. Otherwise, your code seems ok and worked for me in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/aCedAVi/1/edit

Comment: code is right - yes. I want see next:
if value 5000 - then <div id=bla>hello</div>
if value 10000 - then <div id=bla>HELLO TWO!!</div>
...

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the question properly. Can you please add the <div> you want to change in the HTML section of your question and elaborate on what and would you like to see in that div and when.